# Jsoup parse html-string

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have this `Element`:

```
<td id="color" align="center">
Z 29.02-23.05 someText,
<br> 
some.Text2 <a href="man.php?id=111">J. Smith</a> (l.)&nbsp;
</td>
```

How do I get the text after the tag `<br>`, to look like `some.Text2 J. Smith` I tried to find answer in the documentation, but ...

## update

If i use

```
System.out.println(element.select("a").text());
```

i get just only *J. Smith.*. Unfortunately, I don't know how to parse tags like `<br>`

Comment: @Rao, thanks. I dont know about `xpath`. I will go look for information

Comment: @LordAnomander exactly! I forgot about `split`...  This is also nice. Thank! Let's arrange this in response please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Node.childNodes`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes--) could save your life:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow35436825;

import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 35436825
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String html = "<html><body><table><tr><td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">" +
                        "Z 29.02-23.05 someText," +
                        "<br>" +
                        "some.Text2 <a href=\"man.php?id=111\">J. Smith</a> (l.)&nbsp;" +
                        "</td></tr></table></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );
        Element td = doc.getElementById( "color" );
        String text = getText( td );
        System.out.println("Text: " + text);
    }

    /**
     * Get the custom text from the given {@link Element}.
     * @param element The {@link Element} from which get the custom text.
     * @return Returns the custom text.
     */
    private static String getText(Element element) {
        String working = "";
        List<Node> childNodes = element.childNodes();
        boolean brFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.size(); i++) {
            Node child = childNodes.get( i );
             if (child instanceof TextNode) {
                 if(brFound){
                     working += ((TextNode) child).text();
                 }
             }
             if (child instanceof Element) {
                 Element childElement = (Element)child;
                 if(brFound){
                     working += childElement.text();
                 }
                 if(childElement.tagName().equals( "br" )){
                     brFound = true;
                 }
             }
        }
        return working;
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Text: some.Text2 J. Smith (l.)
```

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much! will study `Nodes` in more detail, it`s cool

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only receive the text between two tags, which is not possible with a single `<br/>` tag in your document.

The only option I can think of is to use `split()` in order to receive the second part:

```
String partAfterBr = element.text().split("<br>")[1];
Document relevantPart = JSoup.parse(partAfterBr);
// do whatever you want with the Document in order to receive the necessary parts
```